# How to hide Header and footer printed page?

Tags: theming

I'm using drupal 7 with print module,when printing some node there is some extra content like (date , pager and url) in the header and footer page that will be printed.
I just want to print the content of the node.
How can i remove this content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [module](http://drupal.org/project/print) to print a node
also to remove unwanted region you can change print.tpl.php inside the module

or you can use css

```
@media print
    {
        #header,.menu_background,.breadcrumb,#comments,#sidebar-first,.footer_bg,.node-links { display: none; }
        .node-view{ display: block;height:800px; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using this module already, i removed the regions i want to hide from print.tpl.php.
but nothing happend, they just appear when open print preview page, i think the date and the pager... came from the browser setting.  
Is there any way to set print setting by some code?
thanks

Comment: This content does not from the website it's from the browser.

Comment: are you sure your print.tpl.php is executing? try to clear theme register

Answer (score 1):

copy sites/all/modules/print/print.tpl.php to your theme directory.

edit print.tpl.php and remove codes expect where main content has been printed:

```
<div class="print-content"><?php print $print['content']; ?></div>
```

save file, clear drupal cache